# Action bar icon size inconsistency

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I have an action bar with 4 buttons defined as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarNew"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
        android:title="new" />
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarSave"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
        style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
        android:title="save" />
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarLoad"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_load"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
        android:title="load" />
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarDelete"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        style="@style/ActionButtonStyle"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
        android:title="delete" />
</menu>
```

I used a [Actionbar icon generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5,60) to generate different sized icons and put them in their respective folders.

The problem is, the delete icon looks smaller than the rest of them. Here is a screenshot of my actionbar.

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Because you put it showAsAction as "always", you need to put "ifRoom" instead so it will format to the correct size.

Comment: @Tsunaze That didnt do anything, that just made some of the buttons disappear

Comment: It's normal, if it's on a phone there is not much place in the actionbar, there is a width to not surpass, you can't put actionbar menus all over the bar. You should use icons that describes the better the action you want. Read the guidelines, it's quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have created icons with some text in them.
The word "Delete" is larger than the 3 other words and my guess is that the action bar icon generator scaled the text to make it fit (because all action bar icons have the same width).

I suggest you remove the android:icon attributes and use android:title instead. That will show pieces of text, without scaling the font size.

Alternatively you can continue to use android:icon but with some real icons (not just text in an image). There are a couple of standard action icons available in the [Action Bar Icon Pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html#action-bar-icon-pack) and a lot more can be bought at [androidicons.com](http://www.androidicons.com/)

PS: The android:scaleType attribute is useless on a menu item. The full list of supported attributes is available [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Comment: Yeah I was gonna use android:title but I really want the font to be frizquadrata...

Comment: You can use https://github.com/rulych/Custom-Font-on-Android/blob/master/src/com/rulych/customfont/CustomFont.java and CustomFont.setCustomFont(this, getWindow().getDecorView()) to use a custom font in your Android app. No need to start using drawables all over the place.

Comment: Hi Im trying this but I'm getting a native typeface cannot be made error

Comment: I have never encountered the "native typeface cannot be made" error but other people here on SO have. A quick search might help you.

Comment: Dont worry I fixed it. Thanks for the answer it helped a lot.